# Need to understand JavaScript arrays, objects, and properties

Tags: javascript, jquery

First see how JSON should look like

```
[
    {"ShortCode":"US","Name":"United States"},
    {"ShortCode":"CA","Name":"Canada"},
    {"ShortCode":"AG","Name":"Antigua and/or Barbuda"}
]
```

Code:

```
var countries = [];
map = {};

// This is going to make an HTTP post request to the controller
return $.post('/Client/CountryLookup', { query: query }, function (data) {
    // Loop through and push to the array
    $.each(data, function (i, country) {
    map[country.Name] = country;
    countries.push(country.Name);
});
```

`$post()` will return the above json & i need to parse the json in each loop
 but i do not understand what will be store in map object this line `map[country.Name] = country;`

Suppose country name is "united state" so actually store will be `map['united state']=country` what does it mean?

Even in the save code `map{}` access later like

```
var selectedShortCode = map[item].ShortCode;
```

How map can have a property like `ShortCode` ??

So please discuss this type of coding technique in detail and help me to understand the above code with few more example. thanks

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: You're setting an index (the country name) on an object to be equal to the object containing the country name. So `console.log(map['United States'].Name)` will output `United States`.

Comment: @SLaks why not? Misled by lack of indentation?

Comment: @CupawnTae: He's trying to access `map` after the callback.

Comment: @SLaks possible, but that's not evident from the question - it depends on how he's using the return value from his function - the return value will be a Promise, and if he puts his code in `promise.done()` it'll work just fine. Good point though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `data` after the `$.post` call would be:

```
data = 
[
    { ShortCode: "US", Name: "United States" },
    { ShortCode: "CA", Name: "Canada" },
    { ShortCode: "AG", Name: "Antigua and/or Barbuda" }
];
```

Take a look at the jQuery's [`.each` function documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

It basically can be rewritten as follows:

```
for(var i in data)
{
    var country = data[i];
    map[country.Name] = country;
    countries.push(country.Name);
}
```

So you end up with:

```
map =
{
    "United States": { ShortCode: "US", Name: "United States" },
    "Canada": { ShortCode: "CA", Name: "Canada" },
    "Antigua and/or Barbuda": { ShortCode: "AG", Name: "Antigua and/or Barbuda" }
};

countries = [ "United States", "Canada", "Antigua and/or Barbuda" ];
```

So your code parses json, and outputs all the countries that exist (`countries`) and all the data associated with them (`map`), in two different objects. `countries` can be used to easily itterate through the `map`, but there's no real need for it.

EDIT:

```
var country = data[0];
// country = { ShortCode: "US", Name: "United States" };
map[country.Name] = country;
// map["United States"] = { ShortCode: "US", Name: "United States" };
```

So you can later take `map["United States"]`, it will return you an object `{ ShortCode: "US", Name: "United States" }`, then you can simply access it's property `ShortCode` if you'd like to.

Mind that all variables in JavaScript are passed by reference, and that `myObject["someProperty"]` is exactly the same as `myObject.someProperty`.

Comment: but how we can access like this way  map[item].ShortCode? how ShortCode property used here ? please come with some sample code to understand this dynamic property ? thanks for reply.

Comment: Edited. Hope it helps you understanding.

Answer (score 1):

your map is an object literal defined also known as hash or dictionary or relational array in other languages what basically relates a key(Strin) with a value(anything) in this case relates country names with the actual country object thats why

the map structure after your map[country.Name] = country operations would be
    {
        "United States":{"ShortCode":"US","Name":"United States"},
        "Canada":{"ShortCode":"CA","Name":"Canada"},
        "Antigua and/or Barbuda":{"ShortCode":"AG","Name":"Antigua and/or Barbuda"}
    }

then when you do

```
map["United States"]
```

you get

{"ShortCode":"US","Name":"United States"}

Comment: but how we can access like this way  map[item].ShortCode? how ShortCode property used here ? please come with some sample code to understand this dynamic property ? thanks for reply.

Comment: thats what is writtend in the answer using map[item] is the same as using map["United States"] if item=="United States" map["United States"] is an object containing the properties ShortCode and Name hence map["United States"].ShortCode is "US".